# App detailed-Http Logs in Azure App Service for Linux

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I hosted a web API on azure app service using a docker image (linux)
And for production purpose I need all http requests to be logged.
I tried " Diagnostic settings (preview)" and I selected "Archive to a storage account"
, But when I checked my logs I found all http request data except request & response body and header.

So, is there a way to log this details for debugging purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the response body and header values in the AppServiceHTTPLogs. You can find the description of the log over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/appservicehttplogs.

The feature; however, is still in preview though so that means you can submit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps?query=AppServiceHTTPLogs) asking to include the body and header values.